# Update Dynamics 365 Accounts based on responses from bulk email

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, bulk-email

We are rolling out a new CRM solution. We will require consent from all Accounts to store and share information about their business.

There are about 2500 Accounts.

Is it possible to send out a bulk email to all these Accounts, which will include wording asking for their consent etc, and then to update the 'consent' field on an Account depending on their response to that email?

Comment: GDPR impact? :)

Comment: Could be! I don't know

Answer (score 0):

One approach (that too no code solution) is sending out survey using “Voice of Customer”, capturing survey response against Account, using UI workflow to update the consent field in Account.

[Read more](https://crmtipoftheday.com/992/updating-customer-data-from-survey-responses/)

Comment: Thank you Arun! I'll investigate further and of course mark yours as the answer if it works out

Comment: @SamWhillance how did it go?